# How to change new line in query text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('#collapseExmaplewell').html("Results number is" + t.finished_hits + "<br />Task results are as following:" + t.detailed_results);
```

if `t.detailed_results` is a JSON string, how can I change the `\r` to the right new line character?

Comment: what does the `t.detailed_results` json string look like? What have you tried?

Comment: Is \r towards the end of t.detailed_results ?

Comment: Improved formatting and removed thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following :

```
var str = t.detailed_results.replace(/\r/g, "<br>");
$('#collapseExmaplewell').html("Results number is" + t.finished_hits + "<br />Task results are as following:" + str);
```

You should read more about Regular-Expressions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Please don't use the special word "string" as a variable name!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#collapseExmaplewell').html("Results number is" + t.finished_hits + "<br />Task results are as following:" + t.detailed_results.replace(/\r/g, '\n<br>'));
```